# problems encrypting char*

Tags: c++, vector, cryptography, xor

i have been working on this project for a week and i cant find the solution to my problems.
i'm making an encryptor which can encrypt/decrypt binary file(like .exe, .jpg etc).
i am able to correctly get the data from the binary file using vector.
but i cannot correctly encrypt/decrypt the data from the vector.
some code:

```
    if (encryptFile)
        {
            Crypt crypt;
            //TOencryptfile.open(writeFile, ios::binary | ios::out);

            vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(encryptFile)),(istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
            cout << buffer.size() << endl;
            _getch();
            for (std::vector<char>::iterator i = buffer.begin(); i != buffer.end(); ++i) {
                // encryption that fails
                temp = crypt.getKeyFromString(&*i , key, strlen(&*i));
            }
            TOencryptfile.close();
            encryptFile.close();
        }
```

and the function getKeyFromString:

```
    KEYCRYPT Crypt::getKeyFromString(KEYCRYPT text, KEYCHAR charkey, keylength length) {
    int string_size = std::strlen(text);
    KEYCRYPT textcrypt = new char[string_size + 1];
    std::strcpy(textcrypt, text);
    int key = strlen(charkey);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (strlen(text) != 0) {
            textcrypt[i] = text[i] ^ charkey[i % (sizeof(charkey) / sizeof(char))];
            //keylvl += text[i] ^ (int(charkey) + i) % key;
            //keyfnl += keylvl[i] ^ (int(charkey) - i) * key;
        }
    }
    return textcrypt;
}
```

and at last the types:

```
typedef char* KEYCRYPT;
typedef int KEY;
typedef char* KEYCHAR;
typedef int keylength;
```

**does anybody know a good way to encrypt `*i`?** 
because my way does not work, it does not return the same when calling the function again with `getKeyFromString(temp, key, strlen(temp))`

Comment: The thing pointed to by `i` would appear  to be a single character. Crypto APIs encrypt strings, not single characters.

Comment: thanks! what do you suggest as a solution?

Comment: @waterlight Put the file contents into a string and pass that to the crypto API.

Comment: `getKeyFromString` appears to expect a pointer to a NUL-terminated string as its first parameter. File contents generally wouldn't contain a NUL character.

Comment: @Barmar , could you give an example about how to pass it to a string?

Comment: `getKeyFromString` makes no sense. For the same data pointer, you use as many as three different ways to (try to) determine the size of the data it points to: sometimes with `strlen` (which assumes a NUL-terminated string), other times relying on a parameter passed by the caller, and yet third times with `sizeof` (which is completely wrong: `sizeof(charkey)` is the size of the pointer - usually 4 or 8 depending on your system - and has nothing whatsoever to do with the size of the data pointed to).

Comment: @waterlight Use `std::string buffer` instead of `vector<char> buffer`.

Comment: Please choose a meaningful title and format your sentences properly.

Answer (score 0):

well, according to the response of @Barmar: 
`@waterlight Put the file contents into a string and pass that to the crypto API.` 
i managed to fix the problem. 
all i had to do was:

```
stringstream result;
std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(result, " "));
string now = result.str();
```

and everything worked.
thanks to everybody who replied!!